# ListItems unclickable in Listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, listviewitem, selecteditem

so I am working on my first project with Xamarin Forms and I encountered a problem: Items in my listview are unclickable/Unselectable on Android Emulator. I don't know if it works on iOS. Hope you guys can help me!

Here's what I did:
When the user enters a code in a searchbar, the codes from objects in an observableCollection are compared to the text from the searchbar. if it matches with any of the codes from any objects, the concerned objects are put in an IEnumerable<> that I use for my Listview.ItemSource. I am able to display the Collection, but when I click on an Item, absolutely nothing happens.

Important Note: It works sometimes when I spam a certain item.

Here's the matching codes search method in a View:

```
 async void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CodeStr = RestoSearchBar.Text.ToLower();
            RestaurantListViewModel restaurantViewModel = new RestaurantListViewModel();
            var collec = restaurantViewModel.RestaurantCollector;
            IEnumerable<Restaurant> SearchResults = null;
            SearchResults = collec.Where(R => R.sCode.ToLower().Contains(CodeStr)).ToArray();

            if (SearchResults.Count() == 0)
            {
                await DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, AppResources.ErrorMessage, "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                //Recherche dans la base de données
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page5_ListeRestau(CodeStr, SearchResults));
            }
        }
```

Here's how I pass the IEnumerable parameter:

```
  public Page5_ListeRestau(string CodeResto, IEnumerable<Restaurant> SearchResults)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            code = CodeResto;

            if (SearchResults != null)
            {
                SearchListView.ItemsSource = SearchResults;
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, AppResources.ErrorMessage, "OK");
            }
```

And Here's the XAML for the Listview:

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="SearchListView"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            Grid.Row="2" 
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            SelectedItem="SearchListView_ItemTapped"
            >
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ScrollView>
                                <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" x:Name="Items">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    
                                    
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Source="{Binding sImage}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="50"  />

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding sName}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding sAddress}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>

                                </Grid>

                        </ScrollView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here's what SearchListView_ItemTapped method does:

```
public void SearchListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var details = e.Item as Restaurant;

            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1_menuNavig(details));
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `SearchListView_ItemTapped` do ?

Comment: I don't think a `ScrollView` in your Cell is the best idea and that might be the cause of your problem

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Is there another way to do it without sacrificing the ability to scroll the grid?

Comment: first, get rid of the ScrollView, second use `ItemSelected` instead of `SelectedItem`

Comment: @Jason Wow it was that easy! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItem` is a **property** that contains a reference to the currently selected item.  `ItemSelected` is an **event** that fires when an item is selected.

You want to assign your event handler to the event, not the property.

Also, `ListView` is scrollable, so nesting another scrollable element inside of it is not a good idea.